# Need to transform pivot table into another format

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I want to find some way to change the pivot table back to normal table.

Table 1 has following format:

```
acct type Hr08_C Hr09_C Hr10_C Hr08_H Hr09_H Hr10_H
 1    1     2      3      4      5      6       7
```

Table 2 has following format:

```
acct type hour phone value
  1   1     8    C     2
  1   1     9    C     3
  1   1     10   C     3
  1   1     8    H     5
  1   1     9    H     6
  1   1     10   H     7
```

I want to change the table 1 to table 2 format. Any idea about the query, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do the `UNPIVOT`, then decode the column names:

```
declare @t table (acct int,type int, Hr08_C int, Hr09_C int, Hr10_C int,
                       Hr08_H int, Hr09_H int, Hr10_H int)
insert into @t (acct,type,Hr08_C,Hr09_C,Hr10_C,Hr08_H,Hr09_H,Hr10_H) values
( 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

select
    acct,type,CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(Encoded,3,2)) as hour,
    SUBSTRING(Encoded,6,1) as phone,value
from @t
unpivot (value for Encoded in (Hr08_C,Hr09_C,Hr10_C,Hr08_H,Hr09_H,Hr10_H)) t
```

Result:

```
acct        type        hour        phone value
----------- ----------- ----------- ----- -----------
1           1           8           C     2
1           1           9           C     3
1           1           10          C     4
1           1           8           H     5
1           1           9           H     6
1           1           10          H     7
```

Comment: That works. Never know about the unpivot function. Thanks a lot!!